# Блочное чтение файла - php

Tags: php

Есть очень достаточно огромный файл с кучей текста.**Необходимо его прочесть полностью,но при этом блочно.** *Один блок - от (например) 7 до 10 строк.* Сейчас имею реализацию,которая читает по строкам.Думаю что её можно модернизировать и достичь результата(или я ошибаюсь).

По строкам -

```
$handle = fopen("text.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
 $buffer = fgets($handle);
 echo "$buffer";
     }

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Вам Ипатьев правильно сказал. Зачем усложнять алгоритм то, если он работает отлично!?

Comment: @Visman я про то что как-то доделать и в результате получить работающий скрипт. Благо Шейп помог решить добавлением цикла без изменений в главном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - можно сначала в цикле создать многомерный массив, в который записывать по 7-10 строк, а затем этот массив уже прогонять через цикл и выводить содержание.

Comment: Не будет ли это бить по памяти скрипта?Например кол-во строк от 50к?

Comment: Если вам нужно выводить сразу по 7 строк, то можно в массив писать нужное кол-во, а при достижении его - сразу выводить и чистить массив. В любом случае вам нужна некая временная переменная для хранения N-ого кол-ва строк, чтобы в дальнейшем вывести их.

Comment: И после этого сразу убивать массив?После 7 строк?

Comment: Я тоже подумал о file изначально, но насчет производительности сомневаюсь.

Comment: Да, после 7-ми строк можете его очистить unset(), если вам не нужно будет получить данные вне цикла чтения файла.

Comment: Получилось как-то так.Возможно есть кривые моменты.Подправьте: `$handle = fopen("text.txt", "r");
   while (!feof($handle)) {
    $r = rand(7,10);
    $i=0;
    while ($i<=$r) {
           $buffer = fgets($handle);
        $mas[] = $buffer;
      
     $i++;
    }
    print_r($mas);
    unset($mas);
   }`

Comment: Сойдет, но я бы для цикла использовал for

Answer (score 0):

> Думаю что её можно модернизировать

Можно. Но не нужно.